# Is there a way to create new columns based on the two different conditions applied to two columns on a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a dataset which is fairly large (around 50000 entries) structured in the following way.

| state id | Dist id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 0 | Jammu & Kashmir |
| 32 | 0 | Jammu & Kashmir |
| 32 | 0 | Jammu & Kashmir |
| 32 | 1 | Kupwara |
| 32 | 1 | Kupwara |
| 32 | 4 | Badgam |
| 32 | 4 | Badgam |
| 32 | 14 | Kathua |
| 32 | 14 | Kathua |
| 12 | 0 | Arunachal Pradesh |
| 12 | 0 | Arunachal Pradesh |
| 12 | 10 | Dibang Valley |
| 12 | 10 | Dibang Valley |

To explain this, the state id identifies the state and if the district id happens to be 0 for that particular row, it means the value (which is there in other columns) is for the entire state. However, if the district id happens to be any other number other than 0, the value is for that particular district (which is within the state, given by the state id)

My aim is to get two more columns to this dataset, 'state_name' and 'district_name' such that state_name is filled by all the Name column which has Dist id = 0 and the similar state id. The second column district_name will be filled by the district name.

The expected output is the following table:

| state id | Dist id | Name | state_name | district_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 0 | Jammu & Kashmir | Jammu & Kashmir | - |
| 32 | 0 | Jammu & Kashmir | Jammu & Kashmir | - |
| 32 | 0 | Jammu & Kashmir | Jammu & Kashmir | - |
| 32 | 1 | Kupwara | Jammu & Kashmir | Kupwara |
| 32 | 1 | Kupwara | Jammu & Kashmir | Kupwara |
| 32 | 4 | Badgam | Jammu & Kashmir | Badgam |
| 32 | 4 | Badgam | Jammu & Kashmir | Badgam |
| 32 | 14 | Kathua | Jammu & Kashmir | Kathua |
| 32 | 14 | Kathua | Jammu & Kashmir | Kathua |
| 12 | 0 | Arunachal Pradesh | Arunachal Pradesh | - |
| 12 | 0 | Arunachal Pradesh | Arunachal Pradesh | - |
| 12 | 10 | Dibang Valley | Arunachal Pradesh | Dibang Valley |
| 12 | 10 | Dibang Valley | Arunachal Pradesh | Dibang Valley |

How do I go about this?

Comment: I see your question was deleted, can you try `df11 = df1.set_index(['state','district', df1.groupby(['state','district']).cumcount()])
df22 = df2.set_index([df2['state'],df2['district'], df2.groupby(['state','district']).cumcount()])


df = df22.assign(state = df11['state_name'], district= df11['district_name']).reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try via `loc` accessor and boolean masking and `ffill()` method for forward filling the values of 'state_name' column:

```
df.loc[df['Dist id'].eq(0),'state_name']=df.loc[df['Dist id'].eq(0),'Name']
df.loc[df['Dist id'].ne(0),'district_name']=df.loc[df['Dist id'].ne(0),'Name']
df['state_name']=df['state_name'].ffill()
```

OR

via `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np

df['state_name']=np.where(df['Dist id'].eq(0),df['Name'],np.nan)
df['district_name']=np.where(df['Dist id'].ne(0),df['Name'],np.nan)
df['state_name']=df['state_name'].ffill()
```

output of `df`:

```
    state id  Dist id               Name         state_name  district_name
0         32        0    Jammu & Kashmir    Jammu & Kashmir            NaN
1         32        0    Jammu & Kashmir    Jammu & Kashmir            NaN
2         32        0    Jammu & Kashmir    Jammu & Kashmir            NaN
3         32        1            Kupwara    Jammu & Kashmir        Kupwara
4         32        1            Kupwara    Jammu & Kashmir        Kupwara
5         32        4             Badgam    Jammu & Kashmir         Badgam
6         32        4             Badgam    Jammu & Kashmir         Badgam
7         32       14             Kathua    Jammu & Kashmir         Kathua
8         32       14             Kathua    Jammu & Kashmir         Kathua
9         12        0  Arunachal Pradesh  Arunachal Pradesh            NaN
10        12        0  Arunachal Pradesh  Arunachal Pradesh            NaN
11        12       10      Dibang Valley  Arunachal Pradesh  Dibang Valley
12        12       10      Dibang Valley  Arunachal Pradesh  Dibang Valley
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to duplicate the District ID, and then replace the appropriate IDs with the district name.

For instance, consider the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'District': [1, 4]})
```

[image: first dataframe]

The values are replaced in subsequent data frames:

```
df2=df.replace([1], 'Kupwara')
df3=df2.replace([4], 'Badgam')
```

[image: new dataframe]